# How to create an if statement for the following error?

Tags: java

I would like to know how to add an if statement for the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at Calendar.main(Calendar.java:14)
```

In other words, I would like to display the following text when the following error is triggered, "Error. Please enter the missing elements."

Comment: `if(idx >= myarray.length){ ... }`

Comment: It's hard to be able to advise on the best approach without knowing what the code looks like. We don't know whether the index is dynamic and the array fixed, or vice versa. But yes, basically you'd check whether the array is as large as you expect it to be before indexing into it.

Comment: Maroun that article does not suggest a way to add a condition if the error occurs. I want to do something if the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [try catch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)

```
try{
    //do something that causes that error
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
   //error ocurred
}
```

Comment: That's almost certainly *not* the best way of testing for it though.

Comment: the question was "_how to add an if statement_"...

Comment: He said "I would like to display the following text when the following error is triggered". So if you can, do it with an if instead of a try catch

Comment: How can I do it BanNsN1??

Comment: Just encapsulate your error triggering code inside the try statement and handle it in the catch one.

Comment: Is there a way to add an if statement in try statement

Comment: What do you mean? You can place your code inside the try. Once the error is triggered it will exit that area and jump into the catch block.